# Firebase fetching other user's Images efficiently

Tags: node.js, firebase, image, backend

I have a firebase storage bucket set up for the primary purpose of storing user's profile pictures. Fetching the profile picture of the `currentUser` is simple, as I know the `.uid`. However, fetching the profile pictures for other users is not so straightforward as that first requires a query to my actual database (in this case a graph database) *before* I can even begin fetching their images. This process is aggravated by my backend having a three tier architecture.

So my current process is this:

1. `get` request to `Node.js` backend
2. `Node.js` queries graph database
3. `Node.js` sends data to frontend
4. frontend iteratively fetches profile pictures from other user's `uid`

What seems slow is the fact that my frontend has to wait for the other `uids` before it can even begin fetching the images. Is this unavoidable? Ideally, the images would be fetched concurrently with the info about the users.

Comment: It sounds like you'll need to know the UIDs before you can start retrieving the images for those users. If that happens in step 3, there is indeed no earlier moment to start the image retrieval. Note that this is an educated guess. For a better estimate, it'd help if you show the [minimal, complete/standalone implementation of the system](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess a related question is whether images can be stored natively in a graph database, such that I can fetch them directly when I fetch the other user info (`uid`, name, etc). I assume the answer to this is no, but is something like this possible?

Comment: The question is pretty broad and retrieving images from Storage is generally quick - if you're having speed issues it's most likely due to either how the code is implemented or whatever third party "graph database" you're using - or a combination of both. We store URL's in Firestore and the images in Storage - and retrieve them all the time with no noticeable issues (it's pretty common practice btw). Do you have a detailed coding specific issue? If not, the question is really going to be hard to answer accurately without knowing the details

Comment: It’s more that I’m wondering if there’s a more efficient solution, but as Frank points out, I do indeed need to know the uids before I can get the images.

Answer (score 1):

The title here is `Firebase fetching other user's Images efficiently` but you're using a non-firebase database which makes it a little difficult.

The way I believe you could handle this in Firebase/Firestore would be to have duplicate data (pretty common with NoSQL databases).

Example:
Say you have a timeline feed, you probably wouldn't query the list of posts and then query user info from each of the posts. Instead, I would have a list of timeline posts for a given UID (the customer accessing the system right now), that list would include all the details needed to display the feed without another query. This could be users names, post description, and a link to their pictures based of a known bucket path to a bucket and directory structure and the UIDs. Something like `gs://<my-bucket>/user-images/<a-uid>.jpg`. Again, I don't have much exposure to graph databases so not sure how applicable the technique is there but I believe it could work the same.

Comment: Would the advantage of this approach be that I could fetch the image (along with the other data relevant for a feed) directly from the duplicate database? Or that it would give me a filepath to the image? With the setup I have now, I already have the filepaths to the images after the first query (it's just the uids of the other users, returned in a json with other info).

Comment: Also, the title is relevant--I'm using firebase for image storage. But you're right--I am also using a non-firebase graph db for my primary storage.

Comment: The advantage of the approach is that you don't have to look up the UIDs beacause they are pre-prepopulated in the feed or whatever list of content you're looking at. The idea is it's better to duplicate data in several places than do several queries so build your feed in advance and have all the required info already there. I definitely wouldn't store images in the DB but use URLs to the images in a bucket. You might be able to tie this into a CDN in the future for even faster images loads.